# Add limit orders on side of the chart Plotly

Tags: python, plotly

Trying to add limit order on right side that will show where limit orders was places and volume of that limit. if it sell order make it red and if buy green. If volume of limit order is big make line bigger. There is quick example what I'm looking for.

Here is full code that I have with chart data: https://textbin.net/noz678jlue

[image]

```
    chartData = {'Price': [0.965879, 0.964773, 0.96447, 0.961223, 0.958788, 0.956747, 0.958788, 0.959872, 0.959868, 0.960104, 0.961375, 0.962256, 0.963297, 0.963315, 0.964611, 0.964513, 0.963761, 0.963763, 0.963922, 0.963907, 0.963857, 0.963265, 0.963293, 0.963171, 0.96318, 0.963707, 0.964389, 0.964352, 0.963077, 0.961785, 0.959572, 0.958703, 0.959223, 0.95819, 0.952994, 0.95124, 0.950693, 0.950906, 0.95184, 0.951838, 1.053997, 1.060501, 1.060672, 1.060486, 1.060171, 1.060241, 1.059292, 1.059263, 1.059205, 0.95906, 0.954787, 0.954901, 0.954993, 0.955447, 0.955465, 0.955626, 0.953638, 0.952751, 0.951972, 0.950729, 0.950532, 0.952849, 0.952773, 0.952682, 0.952351, 0.948383, 0.94847, 0.948451, 0.95198, 0.952234, 0.951982, 0.952163, 0.952301, 0.952407, 0.955843, 0.956628, 0.957734, 0.957548, 0.95771, 0.956813, 0.958674, 0.958295, 0.954697, 0.953861, 0.955926, 0.953264, 0.951443, 0.950245, 0.949453, 0.949492, 0.948764, 0.946932, 0.949487, 0.950302, 0.950381, 0.949979, 0.948601, 0.949252, 0.949217, 0.949271, 0.947859, 0.947683, 0.947763, 0.947593, 0.948247, 0.9483, 0.948568, 0.947236, 0.946515, 0.946128, 0.946793, 0.946244, 0.951683, 0.951324, 0.950662, 0.949001, 0.947648, 0.946191, 0.946928, 0.933038, 0.92239, 0.923197, 0.925719, 0.937193, 0.93354, 0.932933, 0.932073, 0.931954, 0.932393, 0.931602, 0.932908, 0.932966, 0.933866, 0.931223, 0.929834, 0.933195, 0.936534, 0.935959, 0.932762, 0.931187, 0.937434, 0.937664, 0.936378, 0.934742, 0.934742], 'Date': [1652117700000, 1652118000000, 1652118300000, 1652118600000, 1652118900000, 1652119200000, 1652119500000, 1652119800000, 1652120100000, 1652120400000, 1652120700000, 1652121000000, 1652121300000, 1652121600000, 1652121900000, 1652122200000, 1652122500000, 1652122800000, 1652123100000, 1652123400000, 1652123700000, 1652124000000, 1652124300000, 1652124600000, 1652124900000, 1652125200000, 1652125500000, 1652125800000, 1652126100000, 1652126400000, 1652126700000, 1652127000000, 1652127300000, 1652127600000, 1652127900000, 1652128200000, 1652128500000, 1652128800000, 1652129100000, 1652129400000, 1652129700000, 1652130000000, 1652130300000, 1652130600000, 1652130900000, 1652131200000, 1652131500000, 1652131800000, 1652132100000, 1652132400000, 1652132700000, 1652133000000, 1652133300000, 1652133600000, 1652133900000, 1652134200000, 1652134500000, 1652134800000, 1652135100000, 1652135400000, 1652135700000, 1652136000000, 1652136300000, 1652136600000, 1652136900000, 1652137200000, 1652137500000, 1652137800000, 1652138100000, 1652138400000, 1652138700000, 1652139000000, 1652139300000, 1652139600000, 1652139900000, 1652140200000, 1652140500000, 1652140800000, 1652141100000, 1652141400000, 1652141700000, 1652142000000, 1652142300000, 1652142600000, 1652142900000, 1652143200000, 1652143500000, 1652143800000, 1652144100000, 1652144400000, 1652144700000, 1652145000000, 1652145300000, 1652145600000, 1652145900000, 1652146200000, 1652146500000, 1652146800000, 1652147100000, 1652147400000, 1652147700000, 1652148000000, 1652148300000, 1652148600000, 1652148900000, 1652149200000, 1652149500000, 1652149800000, 1652150100000, 1652150400000, 1652150700000, 1652151000000, 1652151300000, 1652151600000, 1652151900000, 1652152200000, 1652152500000, 1652152800000, 1652153100000, 1652153400000, 1652153700000, 1652154000000, 1652154300000, 1652154600000, 1652154900000, 1652155200000, 1652155500000, 1652155800000, 1652156100000, 1652156400000, 1652156700000, 1652157000000, 1652157300000, 1652157600000, 1652157900000, 1652158200000, 1652158500000, 1652158800000, 1652159100000, 1652159400000, 1652159700000, 1652160000000, 1652160300000, 1652160600000, 1652160636000]}

    limitOrders = {"BUY":{"0.98": 50000, "0.93": 5555, "0.67": 300000, "0.85": 5555, "0.47": 300000, '0.57': 300000, "0.95": 5555}, "SELL":{"1.00": 50000, "0.83": 5555, "0.67": 300000, "0.75": 5555, "0.57": 300000, '0.67': 300000, "0.85": 5555}}

    eastern = pytz.timezone('US/Eastern')
    df: DataFrame = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(chatData).fillna(method="backfill")
    df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], unit='ms').dt.tz_localize('UTC').dt.tz_convert(eastern)
    x = df['Date']
    y = df['Price']
    layout = Layout(
        autosize=True,
        width=1980,
        height=1080,
        margin=dict(l=10, r=10, t=80, b=10),
        title="<b>TEST</b>",
        paper_bgcolor='rgb(0.03,0.00,0.07)',
        plot_bgcolor='rgb(0.03,0.00,0.07)',
        yaxis_tickformat=".3f",
        title_x=0.5,
        font=dict(
            family="Amarante,cursive",
            size=25,
            color="White")
    )

    fig = go.Figure([
        go.Scatter(x=x, y=1.01 * np.ones_like(y), opacity=0.5, line_width=0, showlegend=False),
        go.Scatter(x=x, y=y, fill='tonexty', fillcolor="#240050", line=dict(color="#940099"), line_shape='spline',
                   opacity=0, showlegend=False)
    ], layout=layout)
    fig.show()
```

Comment: You want the y-axis of the second axis to be price and the x-axis of the second axis to be volume, with color coding by transaction type? I would have a better chance of getting an answer if you have sample data for the chart.

Comment: I update my question, thank you for response!

Answer (score 1):

You can use plotly [shapes](https://plotly.com/python/shapes/#lines-positioned-relative-to-the-plot--to-the-axis-data) to place down the line segments representing limit orders, and [annotations](https://plotly.com/python/text-and-annotations/#text-annotations) to place down the text with the corresponding volume amount. However, you will need to increase the right margin so the annotations are visible.

```
import pytz
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go

chartData = {'Price': [0.965879, 0.964773, 0.96447, 0.961223, 0.958788, 0.956747, 0.958788, 0.959872, 0.959868, 0.960104, 0.961375, 0.962256, 0.963297, 0.963315, 0.964611, 0.964513, 0.963761, 0.963763, 0.963922, 0.963907, 0.963857, 0.963265, 0.963293, 0.963171, 0.96318, 0.963707, 0.964389, 0.964352, 0.963077, 0.961785, 0.959572, 0.958703, 0.959223, 0.95819, 0.952994, 0.95124, 0.950693, 0.950906, 0.95184, 0.951838, 1.053997, 1.060501, 1.060672, 1.060486, 1.060171, 1.060241, 1.059292, 1.059263, 1.059205, 0.95906, 0.954787, 0.954901, 0.954993, 0.955447, 0.955465, 0.955626, 0.953638, 0.952751, 0.951972, 0.950729, 0.950532, 0.952849, 0.952773, 0.952682, 0.952351, 0.948383, 0.94847, 0.948451, 0.95198, 0.952234, 0.951982, 0.952163, 0.952301, 0.952407, 0.955843, 0.956628, 0.957734, 0.957548, 0.95771, 0.956813, 0.958674, 0.958295, 0.954697, 0.953861, 0.955926, 0.953264, 0.951443, 0.950245, 0.949453, 0.949492, 0.948764, 0.946932, 0.949487, 0.950302, 0.950381, 0.949979, 0.948601, 0.949252, 0.949217, 0.949271, 0.947859, 0.947683, 0.947763, 0.947593, 0.948247, 0.9483, 0.948568, 0.947236, 0.946515, 0.946128, 0.946793, 0.946244, 0.951683, 0.951324, 0.950662, 0.949001, 0.947648, 0.946191, 0.946928, 0.933038, 0.92239, 0.923197, 0.925719, 0.937193, 0.93354, 0.932933, 0.932073, 0.931954, 0.932393, 0.931602, 0.932908, 0.932966, 0.933866, 0.931223, 0.929834, 0.933195, 0.936534, 0.935959, 0.932762, 0.931187, 0.937434, 0.937664, 0.936378, 0.934742, 0.934742], 'Date': [1652117700000, 1652118000000, 1652118300000, 1652118600000, 1652118900000, 1652119200000, 1652119500000, 1652119800000, 1652120100000, 1652120400000, 1652120700000, 1652121000000, 1652121300000, 1652121600000, 1652121900000, 1652122200000, 1652122500000, 1652122800000, 1652123100000, 1652123400000, 1652123700000, 1652124000000, 1652124300000, 1652124600000, 1652124900000, 1652125200000, 1652125500000, 1652125800000, 1652126100000, 1652126400000, 1652126700000, 1652127000000, 1652127300000, 1652127600000, 1652127900000, 1652128200000, 1652128500000, 1652128800000, 1652129100000, 1652129400000, 1652129700000, 1652130000000, 1652130300000, 1652130600000, 1652130900000, 1652131200000, 1652131500000, 1652131800000, 1652132100000, 1652132400000, 1652132700000, 1652133000000, 1652133300000, 1652133600000, 1652133900000, 1652134200000, 1652134500000, 1652134800000, 1652135100000, 1652135400000, 1652135700000, 1652136000000, 1652136300000, 1652136600000, 1652136900000, 1652137200000, 1652137500000, 1652137800000, 1652138100000, 1652138400000, 1652138700000, 1652139000000, 1652139300000, 1652139600000, 1652139900000, 1652140200000, 1652140500000, 1652140800000, 1652141100000, 1652141400000, 1652141700000, 1652142000000, 1652142300000, 1652142600000, 1652142900000, 1652143200000, 1652143500000, 1652143800000, 1652144100000, 1652144400000, 1652144700000, 1652145000000, 1652145300000, 1652145600000, 1652145900000, 1652146200000, 1652146500000, 1652146800000, 1652147100000, 1652147400000, 1652147700000, 1652148000000, 1652148300000, 1652148600000, 1652148900000, 1652149200000, 1652149500000, 1652149800000, 1652150100000, 1652150400000, 1652150700000, 1652151000000, 1652151300000, 1652151600000, 1652151900000, 1652152200000, 1652152500000, 1652152800000, 1652153100000, 1652153400000, 1652153700000, 1652154000000, 1652154300000, 1652154600000, 1652154900000, 1652155200000, 1652155500000, 1652155800000, 1652156100000, 1652156400000, 1652156700000, 1652157000000, 1652157300000, 1652157600000, 1652157900000, 1652158200000, 1652158500000, 1652158800000, 1652159100000, 1652159400000, 1652159700000, 1652160000000, 1652160300000, 1652160600000, 1652160636000]}

limitOrders = {"BUY":{"0.98": 50000, "0.93": 5555, "0.67": 300000, "0.85": 5555, "0.47": 300000, '0.57': 300000, "0.95": 5555}, "SELL":{"1.00": 50000, "0.83": 5555, "0.67": 300000, "0.75": 5555, "0.57": 300000, '0.67': 300000, "0.85": 5555}}

eastern = pytz.timezone('US/Eastern')
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(chartData).fillna(method="backfill")
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], unit='ms').dt.tz_localize('UTC').dt.tz_convert(eastern)
x = df['Date']
y = df['Price']
layout = dict(
    autosize=True,
    width=1980,
    height=1080,
    margin=dict(l=10, r=200, t=80, b=10),
    title="<b>TEST</b>",
    paper_bgcolor='rgb(0.03,0.00,0.07)',
    plot_bgcolor='rgb(0.03,0.00,0.07)',
    yaxis_tickformat=".3f",
    title_x=0.5,
    font=dict(
        family="Amarante,cursive",
        size=25,
        color="White")
)

fig = go.Figure([
    go.Scatter(x=x, y=1.01 * np.ones_like(y), opacity=0.5, line_width=0, showlegend=False),
    go.Scatter(x=x, y=y, fill='tonexty', fillcolor="#240050", line=dict(color="#940099"), line_shape='spline',
                opacity=0, showlegend=False)
], layout=layout)

## add limit orders using annotations
## use paper coordinates to determine length in the x direction
max_limit_volume = 500000
max_limit_volume_length = 0.25

for limit_order_name,limit_order_info in limitOrders.items():
    if limit_order_name == "BUY":
        for y_value, volume in limit_order_info.items():
            y_value = float(y_value)
            fig.add_shape(type="line",
                x0=1, y0=y_value, x1=1-0.1*volume/max_limit_volume, y1=y_value,
                line=dict(color="green",width=3)
            )
            fig.add_annotation(
                x=1.05, y=y_value, 
                yshift=-30, xref="paper", 
                text=f"${volume}", font=dict(color="white")
            )
    if limit_order_name == "SELL":
        for y_value, volume in limit_order_info.items():
            y_value = float(y_value)
            fig.add_shape(type="line",
                x0=1, y0=y_value, x1=1-0.1*volume/max_limit_volume, y1=y_value,
                line=dict(color="red",width=3)
            )
            fig.add_annotation(
                x=1.05, y=y_value, 
                yshift=-30e, xref="paper", 
                text=f"${volume}", font=dict(color="white")
            )


fig.update_shapes(dict(xref='paper', yref='y'))
fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: There is a issue with numbers on side, they overlapping each other and make it hard to read. https://ibb.co/jGy5Y5p

Comment: @NoNam4 you have a few options. you could make the font size smaller, or you could stagger the annotations (e.g. place the overlapping annoations at different x paper coordinates)